# Why do some claim that madhyamika is compatible with vedanta,when consciousness is not a cause in madhyamika?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, advaita, buddhism

- https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey claims sunyavaada is compatible with Upanishadic ideas.

but in madhyamika,the 5 elements(earth,water,fire,air and Consciousness) are seperate and do not arise from consciousness.they also do not arise or cease,and momentariness is an upaya therein,so shankara's criticism against momentariness can't refute madhyamika.

Furthermore,this awareness is individual.these five elements are elements because each individual set of the 5 wisdom lights or basis is reified as a material element through beginningless ignorance of their true nature as 5 empty wisdom lights.thats how it is in Prasangika Dzogchen from what I read.We percieve a similar universe because of similar traces.

there is no way to even argue against such view.and I say that as a Advaitin.

Comment: You can quote that part from the book which makes the claim --  "sunyavaada is compatible with Upanishadic ideas". This will give your question more substance.

Comment: give the exact page and section of the book where you read this. Your final comment in the question is asking for opinions.